# Алгоритм сортировки используя нейросеть

Tags: алгоритм, нейронные-сети

Подскажите, пожалуйста, хорошие статьи на тему "Сортировка на нейросети".

Базу про нейросети почитал. Что такое "однослойный перцептрон" представляю.

Почему именно сортировка? Просто разбирают задание, в котором требуется написать алгоритм сортировки чисел, используя нейросеть. При этом весовые коэффиценты должны быть "аналитически" настраиваемыми.

Если вы можете что-то посоветовать по поводу конкретно этого задания, то буду благодарен.

Comment: Откуда такое странное задание? Нейронные сети лучше всего подходят для решения задачи классификации, прогнозирования, управления. Простая нейронная сеть в виде упомянутого вами персептрона, просто позволяет выделять области в пространстве при этом двухслойные только выпуклые фигуры, трехслойные произвольные области, но при этом хорошой результат можно получить если области пространства хорошо разделимы.

Comment: Сам использовал нейросети при написании диплома, для определения пола человека по фотографии лица. Как их использовать в вашей задаче не могу даже предположить, по-моему для этого существуют, более простые и эффективные алгоритмы.

Comment: Такое странное задание из олимпиады.
Более простые и эффективные алгоритмы сортировки конечно существуют, но мне, кажется тут имеется ввиду не просто сортировка по возрастанию/убыванию, а сортировка в зависимости от заданных ранее примеров.
То-есть, в моем понимании это так - если при обучении число 5 всегда было меньше числа 2, то и после обучения сеть должна сортировать исходя из "запомненных" данных ( 2 > 5 )...

Хотя, возможно, я не правильно понимаю "аналитически" настраиваемые коэффициенты, поправьте, если можно

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Проблема сортировки на нейронной сети неоднократно изучалась; к примеру см. [Lin, Hsu (1997)](http://ac.els-cdn.com/S0925231296000409/1-s2.0-S0925231296000409-main.pdf?_tid=bbf9a1f2-3b3b-11e3-967e-00000aacb361&acdnat=1382461529_16c36c3f8c632b6a8ef9c8cf7efe1191) и [Tamburatzis (1999)](https://www.google.nl/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&cad=rja&ved=0CEwQFjAD&url=http%3A%2F%2Fieeexplore.ieee.org%2Fxpls%2Fabs_all.jsp%3Farnumber%3D752799&ei=K69mUqvZIeKCiwKu1YAI&usg=AFQjCNHJe7ry_jhICQXByLxOntFembGubA&sig2=F8MFqIPRRGZpz_sn0LOKcA&bvm=bv.55123115,d.cGE).

Comment: Круто, конечно, но обе ваши ссылки ведут на платные статьи. Как бы не очень comme il faut.

Comment: Благодарю за наводку, жаль, что источники платные. 
Возможно есть статьи небольшие по этой теме?

Вот тут нашел некоторую информацию, правда много математики и не совсем понятно изложено.
Ссылка:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/yip16mkh6bord06/Auto%20Data%20sorting%20using%20neural%20network%20techniques.pdf

Русскоязычной информации по этой теме похоже нет вообще. В рунете такого понятия, как "сортировка на нейросети" похоже, что не имеется.

Comment: Всё же лучше платные источники, чем совсем никаких... @Flasko, я могу выслать статьи мейлом, но для этого мне необходим ваш мейл-адрес.

Comment: Не нашел ЛС, так что пишу тут.
Вот e-mail: getlag@yandex.ru

Спасибо большое.

Comment: Выслал статьи мейлом

Comment: Вижу, спасибо еще раз.

Comment: Мне бы тоже очень пригодились эти статьи. Если не затруднит, вот e-mail: axamulyan@ya.ru. Буду благодарен, если вышлете.
